# How to combine list within a list of a type, to a single immutable list?

Tags: kotlin

I have

```
interface Source {
    val type: String
    val viewTypes: List<String>
}
```

When I have a list of

```
val sources = arrayListOf(source1, source2, source3)
```

I would like to concatenate all sources `viewTypes` into a `List<String>`. Is there a way to achieve that without using for-loop, and get an immutable `List<String>` of `viewTypes`?

The below is wrong as it is producing `List<List<String>>`

```
val listOfListViewType = sources.map { it.viewTypes }
```

Comment: Note that you should use `mutableListOf()` or `listOf()` for a generic use case unless `ArrayList` is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the answer is simply

```
val listOfListViewType = sources.flatMap { it.viewTypes }
```